# CollectionViewCell's container view doesn't fill cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView who's height and width I set with constraints using autolayout. 
In my

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: ...., sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` I return `CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.width-20, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)` and as seen on the image linked below it lines up perfectly fine.

The problem is that the container view (white space) of that cell doesn't fill up the green space (that is the cell's background) at all even though I have set constraints of the containerView to hug left/right/bottom/up with 0 margin.

*What I have tried so far*:

- Make a height constraint for the container view that I assign the collection view's height
- `updateConstraints()` in `cellForItemAt` and inside the cell's class in ```layoutSubview()````
- Set the container view's frame to the collectionView's frame
- `cell.layoutIfNeeded()`in `cellForItemAt`

None of these have solved my problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD2iC.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Here issue related to inset I think. Please use collection delegate method

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right);

}
```

or

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *aFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

[aFlowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)];
```

Swift 5.1

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 15.0
}
```

Comment: @FlatMorning Please add following method once

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
        return 15.0;
    }

Comment: I appreciate you response, but it seems like you are responding with objc code. My question is for Swift.